# Customer (Member) Profile Page

Tags: users, user-profile, custom-field

I have a site where I'd like customers to login and be immediately presented with their profile page (and ONLY their profile page).

On this page they can:
1. See progress reports on their jobs (custom fields)
2. Create new jobs and edit existing jobs

I've added a load of custom fields to the user group but I don't actually want the customers to be exposed to the admin?

Any suggestions for the process of creating this scenario?

Comment: "I don't actually want the customers to be exposed to the admin?" Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide those fields for admin users in the CP? If that's the case you might want to look at this answer https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29843/restrict-a-users-permission-to-only-edit-translatable-fields-on-a-specific-sit/29844#29844

Comment: "...exposed to the admin (CP)".  I mean the user goes to website.com/company-name/  where they see a front-end login.  When logged in the page refreshes to reveal the users details.  There is also a front-end form where they can add additional information which posts into a Section.

Comment: I some time ago did almost the exact same thing you are describing by just following the docs. Start here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html and then "user profile form" etc.It's well described and there's nothing I could add in an answer. Ask again if anything is unclear in the docs.